# Numpy: Find the maximum length of arrays inside another array

Tags: python, numpy

I have a numpy array as the following:

```
import numpy as np
arr = np.array([np.array([1]),np.array([1,2]),np.array([1,2,3]),np.array([1,3,4,2,4,2])])
```

I want a nice numpy function, which gives me the maximum length of the arrays inside my *arr* array.
So I need a numpy function, which return for this example **6**.

This is possible with iteration, but I am looking for a nicer way, perhaps even without `map()`

Any function inside tensorflow or keras would also be possible to use.

Comment: Your "array" is not an array, it's a Python `list`, and that particular list has no way of being transformed in any straightforward way into a `numpy` array (irregular dimension).

Comment: `max(len(a) for a in arr)`? Also, `arr` can't be a numpy array, only with `dtype=object`.

Comment: Error on my side, I forgot the np.array constructor, I just updated my post

Comment: What are the advantages you get by transforming it all to `np.array`s? I don't see any.

Comment: When working with tensorflow and tensors, I need such a construct, since I need to apply numpy functions later on in my data procession

Comment: By "iteration" you mean an explicit for loop?

Comment: I liked the answer of ashraful with : print(len(np.max(arr))), because I didnt knew, that np.max return a whole sublist / array. Unfortunately you deleted your answer, I would accept it, when you post it again

Comment: @MichaelJanz: The answer was wrong. It counted the sum of the elements.Applied to `arr = [[9999],[2,2,2,2,2],[1,1]]` it would have returned `1`.

Comment: Just curious: why would you need a numpy array full of numpy arrays of different length? What is the added value over having those arrays in a Python list? You can't take advantage on numpy anyway, the shape would only be (N,) where N is the number of nested arrays.

Comment: It could occur, when you preprocess your data for a seq2seq model, when padding is not applied yet. Since tensorflow expects for tensor operations a numpy array, lists can not be used in that context. However, that happens rarely, rather in debug steps during preprocessing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We could do:

```
max(map(len, arr))
#6
```

Comment: OP: "This is possible with iteration, but I am looking for a nicer way, perhaps even without map()"

Comment: I think We have to use `map` or loop here

Comment: Agreed. But the OP probably wants to know whether an accelerated implementation exists. Possibly an API either with low level language access or with GPU support

Answer (score 1):

Another simple trick is to use max() function with key argument to return the array with maximum length.

```
len(max(arr, key = len))
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way would be to use the `keras.preprocessing.sequence.pad_sequences()` function.

It pads the sequences to the lenght of the maximum, but in my opinion it creates a high memory usage and depending on the array it might take some time. However, this would be a way without looping:

```
len(keras.preprocessing.sequence.pad_sequences(arr)[0])
```

Comment: I expect this to be much slower than simple looping over array.

Comment: As I said in my answer, yes